# NVIDIA GTX 970 usage not being reported

Tags: nvidia, gpu

My Nvidia GTX 970 isn't reporting its usage at all. It just remains at 0% regardless if it's being used. I'm pretty sure it is being used, because the temperature increases during heavy loads, and I get a high FPS in games.

I've tried using different tools to see if there's just a compatibility issue, but even the Nvidia tools report 0%. I've tried running `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-smi` as root, in case something somewhere had the incorrect permissions, but it still behaved the same.

I'm overclocking it (with a custom fan curve), but I don't think it's related. Setting it to normal doesn't fix this.

I've looked in the logs in case of any hardware issues, but I haven't seen anything that's obviously wrong.

`nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.66.08    Driver Version: 440.66.08    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970     Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 66%   48C    P0    69W / 163W |    952MiB /  4034MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux [computer name] 5.0.0-20-mfutex #21~18.04.1+1valve1+mfutex2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 22 21:05:06 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```